# QTextEdit not displaying

Tags: qt, qtextedit

QTextEdit is not displaying on the window and not displaying "hello".  Not sure what is wrong here?

```
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui/QTextEdit>

    namespace Ui {
        class MainWindow;
    }


    class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
    {
        Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    private:
        QTextEdit *m_textint;
    };
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

-------------


#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QtGui/QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mainWindow;

    mainWindow.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100, 100),
                                 QSize(400, 600)));

    mainWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}

------------------

#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
        : QMainWindow(parent)
    {
        m_textint = new QTextEdit("hello");

        m_textint->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(10, 10),
                                    QSize(50, 200)));

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're using QtCreator, you can attach the QTextEdit() object to what is usually declared centralWidget (QWidget).

I basically took this from the auto-generated code ui_mainwindow.h (using QtCreator).

```
void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)
{
  QWidget* centralWidget = new QWidget(MainWindow);
  centralWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("centralWidget"));

  QTextEdit* textEdit = new QTextEdit(centralWidget);
  textEdit->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("textEdit"));

  textEdit->append("Hello");
}
```

Comment: m_textint = new QTextEdit("hello", this); //needed "this"... your code helped me see  this.. thx